# maven is not a valid Maven home directory

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I get this error message when I try to run my code. The default Maven Home Directory was the m2 folder. I tried using override and I selected where all the Maven files are in the m2 folder and it still gave me this error message. I'm unsure how to fix is any help will be much appreciated.I

Comment: not using Mac OS are you?

Comment: I'm using windows at the moment

Comment: the maven home directory is the one maven is installed to. It contains the bin and conf folder and so on. The .m2 folder in your home directory is a different thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> maven is not a valid Maven home directory

This error message means that the folder named "maven" that you've chosen does not contain maven installation.

> The default Maven Home Directory was the m2 folder.

Normally, by default you'll see either the embeded maven or the value of M2_HOME environment variable. This makes me think that maven is not configured correctly on your machine.

In command prompt, to see where M2_HOME points run: echo %M2_HOME%
Then make sure that this value is either empty or points to where maven is installed.
Finally, make sure maven is installed in folder different than .m2 (where actually it stores its settings).